How to duplicate files in Pythonista
I’m trying to find an easy way to duplicate an existing script file. The Files app cannot access Pythonista files per their documentation.
I’ve manually copied file content to the clipboard,then created an empty file and pasted the clipboard into the new file.
There’s got to be an easier way, like it is in the Pycharm IDE.

A bit janky, but you can do the following:

Share the script (either from the wrench menu in the editor, or from Edit -> select file -> share button in the file browser)
Select Run Pythonista Script
Select Import File

You can then move/rename the new file as you see fit.
